# Feynmann diagram for $W$ boson decay

Tags: standard-model, feynman-diagrams, weak-interaction, chirality

So a $W^{-}$ boson decays into right-handed antineutrino and left-handed lepton with "wrong" helicity. I found that textbook explanation of that process involves lots of handwaving.

I am looking for simple and clear Feynman diagram, possibly involving interaction with background Higgs field. Can anybody provide one?

Comment: You want an explanation of the rarer positive-helicity negative lepton decay coming from the Higgs field in the belly of the W- explained? Which text, page #, etc? Do you understand, firmly & unequivocally, charged pion decay? The overlap of chirality with helicity states?

Comment: If you are asking for the   $R_\xi$ gauge (so not unitary!) $\phi^-\to e \bar \nu$ diagram, it is on p 512 of Cheng & Li, but I very much doubt that is what you are after...